# Using tikz to create fancy chapters

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters

I am trying to use **Stefan Kottwitz**'s chapter style found on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/)
I am using the code as is but I can't seem to be able to compile it successfully. The code is

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}

  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}

      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
% \chapter{Main}
% 
% \section{Section}
% Text
% \begin{thebibliography}{99}
% \bibitem{Test} test reference
% 
% \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

What I get is an error that

> There is no `\begin{document}`

[Here is my log file](http://pastebin.com/ibU37QPS). Any idea on why there is such a problem?

Comment: You have blank lines in `\titleformat{\chapter}{...}` Remove them. Then it works.

Comment: @HarishKumar : I removed and it works! Thank's! Although there are other problems...I'll probably ask a new question!

Comment: Or better convert this into the new question

Comment: As it's solved, I closed it, because there were just paragraph breaks which in fact were not desired but problematic, no further answers needed.